# BeautifulSoup is randomly skipping page data

Tags: beautifulsoup, urllib

The following code is randomly skipping/not returning HTML data.
For example, it may return the data from pages 1,3,and 5 and skip  2 and 4 or it may return data for only one page, and occasionally it returns data for all pages.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re
import threading
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

append_lock = threading.Lock()

url = 'https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/florida/central-disney-orlando/lakeland?bedrooms=studio-1'

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

def get_page(url):
    try:
        p=1
        while p < 101:
            page = str(p)
            p+=1              
            urlPage = (url+'&page='+page)
            soup = make_soup(urlPage)
            print('soup made')
            ListingData = re.findall(r'"listings":(.*?);',str(soup))
            print(len(str(ListingData)))
            with append_lock: 
                if (len(str(ListingData))) > 10:
                    print(len('OK - '+str(ListingData))) 
                    appendFile = open('listings3.txt','a')
                    appendFile.write ('\n'+str(ListingData))
                    appendFile.close
                    print(urlPage)
                else:
                    break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__=='__main__':
    get_page(url)
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex? And what does threading have to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for any help you can offer.  The url is passed from another piece of code and I hope to have a thread for each url (changed by the city and the # of rooms) - the site only goes to 100 pages then I get a 404 error, so I am using those to filter the results.  The information I am looking for (price, # of rooms, # of baths, # of guests possible) is in a string and I didn't know of another way to get these values without regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data you want is in a script tag that has `VRBO.indexMaplisings = ..`, you can use *json.loads* to get a dict of the data and parse whatever you want from that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from json import loads
import re

url = 'https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/florida/central-disney-orlando/lakeland'



with requests.Session() as s:
    with open("listings3.txt", "w") as f:
        for page in range(1, 101):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, params={"page":str(page), "bedrooms":"studio-1"}).content)
            script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("VRBO.indexMaplisings"))
            json_dict = loads(re.search("VRBO.indexMaplisings\s+=\s+(\{.*?\});", script.text).group(1))

            print(json_dict)
            # write whatever you want from the dict to the file i.e
            listings = json_dict["listings"]
```

There also only one *listings* on the page so we use `re.search`.

In your own code you also break if listings is empty so you would never get to the next page, no url is skipped only the ones where listings is `"listings":[]` does not get written as the `len` is not `> 10` and you end the loop in that case. Take this [page](https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/florida/central-disney-orlando/lakeland?bedrooms=studio-1&page=4) as an example :

```
In [57]: s = """VRBO.indexMaplisings = {"hitCount":62,"page":4,"pageSize":50,"pageCount":2,"fromRecord":0,"toRecord":0,"hasMapViewport":true,"mapViewport":{"southwest":{"latitude":27.952582,"longitude":-82.0559339},"northeast":{"latitude":28.1722891,"longitude":-81.838785}},"minLatitude":27.952582,"maxLatitude":28.1722891,"minLongitude":-82.0559339,"maxLongitude":-81.838785,"showingPopularityBadge":false,"showingPopularityBadgeOnADL":false,"listings":[]};"""


In [58]: re.findall(r'"listings":(.*?);',s)
Out[58]: ['[]}']
In [59]: len(str(re.findall(r'"listings":(.*?);',s)))
Out[59]: 7 # you break
```

Also the lock is not needed as you are running the code in a single thread.

Your regex is also very brittle as it relies on the json data ending in `"listings":whatever;` which may not always be the case.

This will get all the data you want from each listing and keep looping until there are no listings:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from json import loads, dump
import re
from itertools import count

url = 'https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/florida/central-disney-orlando/lakeland'
start = "https://www.vrbo.com/vacation-rentals/usa/florida/central-disney-orlando/lakeland?bedrooms=studio-1"
required_items = ('priceRange', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sleeps', 'latitude', 'longitude')



def parse_json(soup, required_items):
    script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("VRBO.indexMaplisings"))
    data = loads(re.search("VRBO.indexMaplisings\s+=\s+(\{.*?\});", script.text).group(1))
    return [{item: dct[item] for item in required_items} for dct in data["listings"]]

with requests.Session() as s:
    all_listings = []
    with open("listings3.txt", "w") as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        all_listings.extend(parse_json(soup, required_items))
        # start at second page 
        for page in count(2):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, params={"page": str(page), "bedrooms": "studio-1"}))
            # get next lists
            listings = parse_json(soup, required_items)
            # if the list returned is empty, there are no more listings so break and dump the list of dicts.
            if not listings:
                dump(all_listings, f)
                break
            all_listings.extend(listings)
```

Using the url from your question you will see dicts in your file like:

```
[{"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.992795, "priceRange": "$171", "latitude": 27.985789}, {"bathrooms": "4.5", "sleeps": "9", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -82.049959, "priceRange": "$521", "latitude": 27.953187}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -82.00481415, "priceRange": "$123", "latitude": 28.13424492}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.9561009, "priceRange": "$99", "latitude": 28.030533}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.956359, "priceRange": "$159", "latitude": 28.030599}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.930784, "priceRange": "$160", "latitude": 27.974206}, {"bathrooms": "2.5", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.926244, "priceRange": "$182", "latitude": 27.983273}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.947685, "priceRange": "$111", "latitude": 28.038347}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.881451, "priceRange": "$119", "latitude": 27.957731}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "5", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.89933963, "priceRange": "$99", "latitude": 27.95342536}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -82.0014659, "priceRange": "$99", "latitude": 28.136643}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.9511537, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.0338166}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "2 BR", "longitude": -81.98120765, "priceRange": "$93", "latitude": 28.01678189}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "2 BR", "longitude": -81.8435977, "priceRange": "$90", "latitude": 28.0606127}, {"bathrooms": "1.5", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.950716, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.080144}, {"bathrooms": "2.5", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.9236399, "priceRange": "$395", "latitude": 28.1432271}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.99124822, "priceRange": "$47", "latitude": 28.04222758}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "2 BR", "longitude": -81.944574, "priceRange": "$68", "latitude": 28.120374}, {"bathrooms": "4", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.998696, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.042091}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.67315095, "priceRange": "$87", "latitude": 28.3128085}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.626667, "priceRange": "$86", "latitude": 28.134241}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.693512, "priceRange": "$83", "latitude": 28.37316}, {"bathrooms": "5.5", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.55154, "priceRange": "$173", "latitude": 28.212491}, {"bathrooms": "3.5", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.46624088, "priceRange": "$98", "latitude": 28.2903145}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.664399, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.269115}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "2 BR", "longitude": -81.595507, "priceRange": "$98", "latitude": 28.304027}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.69073486, "priceRange": "$117", "latitude": 28.37716103}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "2 BR", "longitude": -81.654253, "priceRange": "$128", "latitude": 28.3490513}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.632586, "priceRange": "$97", "latitude": 28.125347}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "9", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.66142, "priceRange": "$120", "latitude": 28.28653}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.632741, "priceRange": "$112", "latitude": 28.125344}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.680034, "priceRange": "$118", "latitude": 28.317691}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "9", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.463991, "priceRange": "$99", "latitude": 28.3262611}, {"bathrooms": "4", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.65518295, "priceRange": "$200", "latitude": 28.2622737}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.6602939, "priceRange": "$85", "latitude": 28.321667}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.66710037, "priceRange": "$110", "latitude": 28.27817663}, {"bathrooms": "2.5+", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.6111449, "priceRange": "$129", "latitude": 28.331692}, {"bathrooms": "6", "sleeps": "16", "bedrooms": "8 BR", "longitude": -81.6439374, "priceRange": "$377", "latitude": 28.311986}, {"bathrooms": "4", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.562012, "priceRange": "$157", "latitude": 28.215793}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.659387, "priceRange": "$104", "latitude": 28.287149}, {"bathrooms": "4", "sleeps": "10", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.60357349, "priceRange": "$219", "latitude": 28.2390289}, {"bathrooms": "2.5", "sleeps": "9", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.48851, "priceRange": "$102", "latitude": 28.33821}, {"bathrooms": "6", "sleeps": "16", "bedrooms": "8 BR", "longitude": -81.64307894, "priceRange": "$374", "latitude": 28.31244195}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.624088, "priceRange": "$104", "latitude": 28.33457}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.6965, "priceRange": "$85", "latitude": 28.37845}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "3 BR", "longitude": -81.66819593, "priceRange": "$90", "latitude": 28.3699695}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "4 BR", "longitude": -81.67586517, "priceRange": "$134", "latitude": 28.29595757}, {"bathrooms": "3.5", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "6 BR", "longitude": -81.580903, "priceRange": "$133", "latitude": 28.248328}, {"bathrooms": "3", "sleeps": "13", "bedrooms": "5 BR", "longitude": -81.67056084, "priceRange": "$163", "latitude": 28.30456961}, {"bathrooms": "5.5+", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "6 BR", "longitude": -81.567669, "priceRange": "$296", "latitude": 28.215151}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$153", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5962564, "priceRange": "$200", "latitude": 28.3306698}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.489502, "priceRange": "$87", "latitude": 28.328199}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$163", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5963092, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.3307724}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.481789, "priceRange": "$87", "latitude": 28.338421}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4736379, "priceRange": "$149", "latitude": 28.392336}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.51717147, "priceRange": "$219", "latitude": 28.3271902}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.55375673, "priceRange": "$425", "latitude": 28.36569065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.46711522, "priceRange": "$102", "latitude": 28.45665002}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.52264674, "priceRange": "$490", "latitude": 28.37609096}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.6553846, "priceRange": "$101", "latitude": 28.3502409}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.610405, "priceRange": "$131", "latitude": 28.268601}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5962564, "priceRange": "$205", "latitude": 28.3306698}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5963092, "priceRange": "$144", "latitude": 28.3307724}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$171", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4788332, "priceRange": "$188", "latitude": 28.4030052}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.489502, "priceRange": "$87", "latitude": 28.328199}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5963092, "priceRange": "$143", "latitude": 28.3307724}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5963092, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.3307724}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.489502, "priceRange": "$86", "latitude": 28.328199}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5962564, "priceRange": "$163", "latitude": 28.3306698}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5962322, "priceRange": "$143", "latitude": 28.330707}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$115", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "2", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.5027632, "priceRange": "$96", "latitude": 28.3902312}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5000077, "priceRange": "$120", "latitude": 28.3871398}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5893128, "priceRange": "$140", "latitude": 28.3118658}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5983575, "priceRange": "$186", "latitude": 28.33010353}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5959618, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.3271023}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.6034359, "priceRange": "$101", "latitude": 28.3172395}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$115", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$175", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.625746, "priceRange": "$128", "latitude": 28.353955}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5914525, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.3338545}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.592849, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.344393}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5345055, "priceRange": "$83", "latitude": 28.3413117}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$143", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "8", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.626505, "priceRange": "$256", "latitude": 28.287416}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.55401422, "priceRange": "$425", "latitude": 28.36561513}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$140", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5303303, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.3346629}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5977362, "priceRange": "$171", "latitude": 28.3295065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$139", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5390417, "priceRange": "$425", "latitude": 28.3599308}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.53830869, "priceRange": "$375", "latitude": 28.39356197}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4756422, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.4280449}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.5914525, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.3338545}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4788332, "priceRange": "$179", "latitude": 28.4030052}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$110", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$113", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4848835, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.3285948}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4863782, "priceRange": "$117", "latitude": 28.3267232}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5000077, "priceRange": "$129", "latitude": 28.3871398}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4788332, "priceRange": "$250", "latitude": 28.4030052}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4756422, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.4280449}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4863782, "priceRange": "$155", "latitude": 28.3267232}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "2", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.527306, "priceRange": "$600", "latitude": 28.403354}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5857833, "priceRange": "$157", "latitude": 28.33901813}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5977362, "priceRange": "$122", "latitude": 28.3295065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.533477, "priceRange": "$260", "latitude": 28.3741026}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5227433, "priceRange": "$500", "latitude": 28.3760532}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.527306, "priceRange": "$200", "latitude": 28.403354}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.5977362, "priceRange": "$93", "latitude": 28.3295065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.5914525, "priceRange": "$97", "latitude": 28.3338545}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.4755988, "priceRange": "$100", "latitude": 28.4280396}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.48583984, "priceRange": "$104", "latitude": 28.33708}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.490624, "priceRange": "$93", "latitude": 28.330523}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.497887, "priceRange": "$83", "latitude": 28.38872}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5916639, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.3283343}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.6250875, "priceRange": "", "latitude": 28.3492164}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5977362, "priceRange": "$125", "latitude": 28.3295065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5227433, "priceRange": "$600", "latitude": 28.3760532}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5043942, "priceRange": "$179", "latitude": 28.3677156}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.760721, "priceRange": "$52", "latitude": 27.996537}, {"bathrooms": "0", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.468911, "priceRange": "$140", "latitude": 28.273777}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5390417, "priceRange": "$142", "latitude": 28.3599308}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "5", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.6056994, "priceRange": "$332", "latitude": 28.3542586}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "6", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.501109, "priceRange": "$125", "latitude": 28.36809872}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5011427, "priceRange": "$86", "latitude": 28.3894554}, {"bathrooms": "4", "sleeps": "15", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.658196, "priceRange": "$160", "latitude": 28.291463}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "2", "sleeps": "12", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$152", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.532309, "priceRange": "$114", "latitude": 28.3378335}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.4692035, "priceRange": "$157", "latitude": 28.4059774}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5977362, "priceRange": "$286", "latitude": 28.3295065}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.489925, "priceRange": "$299", "latitude": 28.38609}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.489925, "priceRange": "$395", "latitude": 28.38609}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.52647071, "priceRange": "$264", "latitude": 28.397612}, {"bathrooms": "1", "sleeps": "4", "bedrooms": "1 BR", "longitude": -81.5960609, "priceRange": "$135", "latitude": 28.330631}, {"bathrooms": "0", "sleeps": "2", "bedrooms": "Studio", "longitude": -81.489925, "priceRange": "$147", "latitude": 28.38609}]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  It works great, although I am a little lost getting the json_dict to the listings.txt file.  How would you suggest to stop the thread when it reaches the end of the listings (like in your example above where page 4 doesn't have any listings)?

Comment: @JustinHill, why would you want to stop? Other pages have listing after. Also do you really want all the data or just some that is contained in the dict? If you do want all written to the file just forget the loads logic and `f.write(re.search("VRBO.indexMaplisings\s+=\s+(\{.*?\});", script.text).group(1)) + u"\n"`

Comment: I apologize for any confusion - I am very new to python and may not be asking the right questions.  I would like the thread to stop once all the listings for the city have been returned.  In some cases, this is one page and in others as many as 100 pages.  I would like to loop until the last page with listings is returned.  I only want the 'priceRange', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sleep', 'latitude', and 'longitude' data for the individual listings.  I would like all of the threads (for 10 cities, and 6 bedroom filters - 60 threads) to write to the same file.

Comment: Every page has a "listings" key, are you saying keep looping until the associated list is empty?

Comment: Yes.  I would like it to loop until there are no more 'listings' for each city.  Thanks for all your help, I learned quite a bit yesterday because of it.

Comment: @JustinHill, there are 55 pages for Lakeland, FL, USA, so you want all those listings?

Comment: Yes, all 55 pages.  With the help you provided yesterday I was able to get it to work.  Your newest code changes makes it work perfectly.  Thanks again for all of your help.